# Is there a way to precisely log password reset time on Windows OS?

Tags: dll, ldap, domaincontroller, local-security-authority

Specifically, I am trying to test the amount of overhead time that will come with installing a new Password Filter DLL in a domain's DC. What would the best way of approximating the time taken from when a password change request is made through the LSA to the time it is successfully committed to the Security Accounts Manager? Is there some logging functionality already done that may be useful for this purpose?

Comment: Are you sure that the time between a password change request and its commital is really a critical path for your system? It's rather a rare operation, in the scheme of things.

Comment: It's for testing the overhead time I get with an additional Password Filter DLL that checks against whether users are resetting to breached passwords in a large database.